# Can I set a models.imageURL as background image in a html container?

Tags: html, css, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to create a blog on Django in my learning process and I was wondering if it's possible to use a models.imageUrl as a background image for a post template.

I'm not even sure it's possible to do so, is it?

thanks in advance!

this is my styles code insinde my html div:

```
<div class="showcase" style="background-image: url(/static/media/image.jpeg); background-size: cover; background-position: center; padding: 140px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you did not provide your code for the model, but let me try this.

Generally speaking you insert images in your html template like this. Therefore you have to store that img in your staticfiles first.

```
{% load static %}
<div class="showcase" style="background-image: {% static 'path/to/image.png' %}; background-size: cover; background-position: center; padding: 140px;">
```

If your image is bound to a model field though, you would do it like this: Remember that your view, that serves that template has to pass `MyModel` to the template with the conventional name of `object`.

models.py

```py
class MyModel(models.Model)
    back_gr_img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="path/to/img/")
```

template:

```
<div class="showcase" style="background-image: {{ object.back_gr_img.url }}; background-size: cover; background-position: center; padding: 140px;">
```

Read more about the `url` call [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url)

## Edit after OP's comment providing his model

models.py:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    slug = models.SlugField() 
    intro = models.TextField(max_length=400) 
    body = models.TextField() 
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/", blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py:

```py
def post_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            object = form.save()
            return render(request, 'template_with_background.html', {'object': object})
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

template:

```
<div class="showcase" style="background-image: {{ object.image.url }}; background-size: cover; background-position: center; padding: 140px;">
```

Comment: Hi, yeah sorry i didn't put my models code!

that's how it looks right now:

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    intro = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/", blank=True, null=True),

so i'd like my template to show this imageField as the background, so whenever i create a new post, this imageGield would automatically be the background of the header of the html

Comment: I adjusted my answer.

Comment: with my views like this:

def postDetail(request, category_slug, slug):
    # if request is POST
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()

            return redirect("postDetail", slug=slug)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, "blog/postdetail.html", {
            "post": post,
            "form": form,
        })

i make those changes and it doesn't work, do i need to adapt?

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm really a beginner...